# MySQL does not follow Ubuntu System Time Zone

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7, timezone, docker

An Ubuntu 16.04 server has it's time zone set to `America/New_York` using the command

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York
```

This is confirmed by running the commands

**timedatectl status | grep "Time zone"**

```
 Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
```

**date +%Z**

```
EST
```

However MySQL thinks that the system's time zone is still `UTC`. MySQL 5.7 server (running within a docker container) has been restarted befpre querying for the MySQL timezone

**Output of MySQL Query `show global variables like '%time_zone'`**

```
system_time_zone UTC
time_zone SYSTEM
```

Did something go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you run mysql inside docker. Docker needs timezone as an environment variable as follows:

Add the following to mysql startup command in docker:

```
-e TZ='America/New_York'
```

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/320